# SQL Server 2008R2 Full outer join not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, full-outer-join

I am trying to run the below query

```
SELECT      mr.AsofDate as date,
            mr.FA,
            mr.TPNL as tpnl,
            mr.MPNL as mpnl,
            mrf.tpnl as mrfTpnl,
            mrf.cpnl as mrfCpnl
FROM        vw_daily mr
FULL        OUTER JOIN mrfeeddaily  mrf
ON          mr.FA = mrf.book and mr.AsofDate = mrf.AsOfDate
WHERE       mr.AsofDate = '20141121'
```

But i end up getting only rows from the first View `vw_daily` and the columns from `mrfeeddaily` are NULL, doesn't Full join return all non matching rows as well ? what am i missing.

There is no common data between the view and the table.

Answer (score 3):

Move the filter to `ON` condition

`ON` tells what are the rows to used for Joining but `where` clause filters the result of `join`.

Only matched rows in `vw_daily` table is going to have value in `asofdate` so the filtering the rows in `Where` clause is going to do implicit conversion from `FULL OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT mr.asofdate AS date, 
       mr.fa, 
       mr.tpnl     AS tpnl, 
       mr.mpnl     AS mpnl, 
       mrf.tpnl    AS mrfTpnl, 
       mrf.cpnl    AS mrfCpnl 
FROM   vw_daily mr 
       FULL OUTER JOIN mrfeeddaily mrf 
                    ON mr.fa = mrf.book 
                       AND mr.asofdate = mrf.asofdate 
                       AND mr.asofdate = '20141121'
```

Comment: Hi, on doing that I get all the rows in the vw_daily table (130 Million) for all the historic dates and all the rows from mrfeeddaily as opposed to what i want 3900 rows from vw_daily table for AsOfDate 20141121 and 95 rows from mrfeeddaily table for AsOfDate 20141121 so total of 3995 in my result set, please let me know if I am not asking the correct question and i will change it

Answer (score 0):

Filter the condition in your join.

```
SELECT mr.AsofDate AS date, mr.FA, mr.TPNL AS tpnl, mr.MPNL AS mpnl,  mrf.tpnl AS mrfTpnl, mrf.cpnl AS mrfCpnl
FROM vw_daily mr
FULL OUTER JOIN mrfeeddaily  mrf ON mr.FA = mrf.book 
AND mr.AsofDate = mrf.AsOfDate 
AND mr.AsofDate = '20141121'
```

Comment: Hi @matt, on doing that I get all the rows in the vw_daily table (130 Million) for all the historic dates and all the rows from mrfeeddaily as opposed to what i want 3900 rows from vw_daily table for AsOfDate 20141121 and 95 rows from mrfeeddaily table for AsOfDate 20141121 so total of 3995 in my result set, please let me know if I am not asking the correct question and i will change it